# Creating a responive staggered row design without Javascript

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design a staggered layout for some blocks of content, where each block is the exact same width but may have a different height. However, each item is sequential, so they need to be more or less legible from left to right (ie: Column 1 has items 1 and 4, Column 2 has items 2 and 5, and Column 3 has item 3)

This is my idea: http://oi59.tinypic.com/24b66hw.jpg

This was my first idea:

```
<?php
    $arr = array();
    $arr[] = array('title' => 'Day 1', 'img' => '/image1.png', 'text' => 'Text for item 1');
    $arr[] = array('title' => 'Day 2', 'img' => '/image2.png', 'text' => 'Text for item 2');
    $arr[] = array('title' => 'Day 3', 'img' => '/image3.png', 'text' => 'Text for item 3');
    $arr[] = array('title' => 'Day 4', 'img' => '/image4.png', 'text' => 'Text for item 4');
    $arr[] = array('title' => 'Day 5', 'img' => '/image5.png', 'text' => 'Text for item 5');

    $cols = array();
    $cols[0] = array();
    $cols[1] = array();
    $cols[2] = array();

    for($x = 0; $x <= count($arr); $x+=3) {
        $cols[0][] = $arr[$x];

        if (isset($arr[$x+1])) {
            $cols[1][] = $arr[$x+1];
        }

        if (isset($arr[$x+2])) {
            $cols[2][] = $arr[$x+2];
        }
    }

    foreach($cols as $key => $col) {
        echo '<div class="col'.$key.'">';
        foreach($col as $item) {
            echo '<div class="row-item">';
            echo 'Title: '.$item['title'].'<br />';
            echo 'Image: '.$item['img'].'<br />';
            echo 'Text: '.$item['text'];
            echo '</div>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
?>
```

Which would generate this:

```
<div class="col0">
    <div class="row-item">
        Title: Day 1<br>
        Image: /image1.png<br>
        Text: Text for item 1
    </div>


    <div class="row-item">
        Title: Day 4<br>
        Image: /image4.png<br>
        Text: Text for item 4
    </div>
</div>


<div class="col1">
    <div class="row-item">
        Title: Day 2<br>
        Image: /image2.png<br>
        Text: Text for item 2
    </div>


    <div class="row-item">
        Title: Day 5<br>
        Image: /image5.png<br>
        Text: Text for item 5
    </div>
</div>


<div class="col2">
    <div class="row-item">
        Title: Day 3<br>
        Image: /image3.png<br>
        Text: Text for item 3
    </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, I ran into a problem when I was told the layout has to be responsive, and when displayed on smaller screens, there is only one row instead of three, like this: http://oi62.tinypic.com/2hfudj6.jpg

I can't seem to think of any way around this particular problem outside of either using JavaScript to reorganize the block on small screens, or have a separate output of the blocks that appears only on small screens.

Comment: Is it a requirement that you fit 3 columns on the screen, even in a mobile viewport?

Comment: I can recommend http://isotope.metafizzy.co/ its easy and responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, I would point you in the direction of HTML5 CSS3 `columns`. Chris Coyier does [a nice writeup here](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/columns/), and a [CodePen here](http://codepen.io/katydecorah/pen/7db740bc9ff28a1f7fdd70bcce257860).

This is a simple CSS fix. You can change them in @media queries. If I'm not mistaken, Pinterest uses this, plus a Javascript fallback for non-supporting browsers.

Now this would mean your content will flow (in source order) top to bottom *then* left to right, so:

```
1 | 5 | 9
2 | 6 | 10
3 | 7 | 11
4 | 8 | 12
```

...like newspaper columns.

Comment: Unfortunately it has to be legible from left to right, then top to bottom.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure that could be done without quite a bit of JS logic... especially when it starts scaling down. Have you looked into `flexbox`? I haven't dug into it since I'm stuck supporting IE8, but I hear great things about it. I don't know if it will stagger vertically like you want, though: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

PHP is probably unnecessary as CSS pseudoclasses alone should do a much cleaner (and less exhaustive) job.

The first example allows you to target every odd and even occurring instance of the div element `.col`:

```
 .col:nth-child(odd) {
            /* Your Styles */
  }

 .col:nth-child(even) {
            /* Your Styles */
  }
```

Or for more specific control, this will allow you to target the element by the order of appearance:

```
 .col:nth-child(1) {
            /* Your Styles */
  }

 .col:nth-child(2) {
            /* Your Styles */
  }

 .col:nth-child(3) {
            /* Your Styles */
  }
```

Now, of course, that will help you set up the columns for a desktop environment. What about mobile or other viewports? Media queries.

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
        .col:nth-child(1) {
              /* Your Styles */
          }
   }
```

This will allow you to define the behavior of the individual columns on a smaller viewport. Replicate the media query as much as you need to to precisely pinpoint exactly how they should behave across all screen sizes.